# Is it permitted to pray for the guy whom I love to get him as life partner? What is the best way to pray?

Tags: salat, love

I am Fatema from Bangladesh. I love a boy and he also loves me. We got close many times, but never engaged in sex and keep praying to the Almighty to keep us together through to marriage, in a halal way.

Recently, he has gone to UK for study purposes.  His family is planning for his marriage over there.  He is the eldest son of his family.  His family needs urgent financial support from him and he cannot deny the responsibility to his family.  I also don't want him to deny that. But I also don't want to lose him, although I am unable to move to UK. The situation is too difficult. I don't know what to do: only one door is open, and that door is to pray to the Almighty. It will be possible only if Allah lets a miracle happen.

How should I pray to get him as my husband?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly recommed you to take our 2 min. [tour] and check our [help].

Comment: Talk to your parents as difficult as it may be. Once they agree, maybe your father can reach out to his father to sort this out. If there is khair, may Allah  marry the two of  you else provide you both with sabr & hidayah. Salaam!

Comment: We should pray to Allah swt to send us the right husband / wife. Falling in love with someone and then do prayers to Allah that this is the right one to marry does not work. Don't marry the one you love, love the one you marry. A successful marriage needs more than a feeling which can fade away after some time.

Answer (score -1):

The pray it is the same ,muslims don't have different prays expect in Eid pray and dead prays if you want anything to happen just call Allah ,you can pray then call Allah to marry from this person but its not condition to call Allah (in Arabic doaa' (دعاء)) that you must pray to answer you. Any time you need Allah you can ask him, Allah said in Quran :(اذا سألك عبادي عني فإني قريب أجيب دعوة الداع إذا دعان ) which mean (if  you asked Allah he is so so near of us he answer who asked him just ask)  if  if you get lateness in the answer just know that was the best for you and for your life...... I'm sorry am not so perfect in english if you don't understand anything please say

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly recommed you to take our 2 min. [tour] and check our [help] and read [answer].